# Cannot access GitLab registry during GitLab CI job in another project

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-registry

I have this setup:

> Project A with GitLab Registry setup and my image within it

[image]

> Project B without GitLab Registry, where I want to use image from
>   registry from Project A.

Within Project B I have this `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/patrykkrawczyk/backend-mock-ci-image:latest

stages:
  - install

install:
  stage: install
  script:
    - npm i
```

Also, for Project B within my CI Variables I have setup `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` variable that is not protected and not masked:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "registry.gitlab.com": {
            "auth": "xxx"
        }
    }
}
```

Where `xxx` is the base64 format of my username and personal access token with all permissions.

However, when I run my job this happens:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.0.0-rc1 (58d8360f)
  on docker-auto-scale 0277ea0f
Using Docker executor with image registry.gitlab.com/patrykkrawczyk/backend-mock-ci-image:latest ...
Pulling docker image registry.gitlab.com/patrykkrawczyk/backend-mock-ci-image:latest ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/patrykkrawczyk/backend-mock-ci-image/manifests/latest: unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied (executor_docker.go:175:0s)
```

What's happening? I can successfully do a `docker login` from my terminal and pull the image.

Comment: Probably related https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2673